# Como fazer o executável do meu programa?

Tags: java

a interface gráfica já está construída e ela roda se eu compilar.
como criar o executável para rodar em qualquer máquina?

Comment: Você está usando alguma IDE?

Comment: Qual a plataforma? Um arquivo `jar` deve funcionar em qualquer plataforma que dê suporte a Java, mas um "executável" só vai funcionar numa plataforma específica (ex.: Windows, Linux, Mac).

Comment: eu tentei abrir o .jar que estava dentro da pasta NetBeansProjects\Projeto\dist , mas não funcionou

Comment: no netbeans é no menu executar->limpar e contruir projeto (Shift + F11) ele gera o .jar e da o caminho para a pasta onde gerou

Comment: O jar gerado deu problema no manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende do IDE que estiver a usar.
Na linha de comandos ficaria algo assim:

```
java NomeDoPrograma
```

Note que o nome do programa nao acaba com .class
Se o programa tiver varios pacotes entao tera que fazer assim:

```
java caminho/para/o/pacote/com/a/classe/principal/NomeDoPrograma
```

Se estiver no NetBeans basta clicar no Botao que tem um martelo e uma vassoura em cima, e isso ira criar um ficheiro .jar em que pode encontrar no caminho do seu programa onde o mesmo esta guardado.
o .jar devera ficar +/- desta maneira

```
/NetBeansProjects/NomeDoProjeto/dist
```

o jar devera se encontrar la.

Answer (score 1):

Para distribuir/executar um programa Java, basicamente você deve gerar o .jar  (que depende de como você fez o projeto, se usou Maven por exemplo executaria a fase package) e também se está usando alguma IDE. 
Com o .jar pronto, deve criar arquivos de lote para executar em cada ambiente. No windows será um .bat e no linux e mac .sh.
Nestes arquivos você poderá (se necessário) setar propriedades como JAVA_HOME, JAVA_OPTS, classpath, etc.
Em um dos projetos que trabalho há exemplos:  https://github.com/demoiselle/nimble/tree/master/impl/core/src/main/scripts